# Multiple cameras preview issue on Camera2 Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-camerax

how can i open two different 'back facing' physical cameras and set preview?

I want to use both Camera Id 0 (with physical Camera Ids [2,5,6,7]) and Camera Id 2 simultaneously..

I could get one back facing logical camera and front facing camera at the same time, but failed to get two back facing physical cameras with error on logcat

```
CameraService           cameraserver          E     Conflicts with: Device 2, client package com.young.camera2demoapp (PID 30624, score -2, state 2)
```

```
for (String cameraId : cameraIdArray) {
    if (cameraId.equals(cameraID_0)) {
        TextureView textureView = textureView_1;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {...});
    else if(cameraId.equals(cameraID_2)){
        TextureView textureView = textureView_1;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {...});
```

using for loop for targeting cameraIds (in my case id 0 and 2), I set two surfaceTextureListeners for each camera and 'openCamera()' inside of 'onSurfaceTextureAvailable()'

```
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height){
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>();
            outputSurfaces.add(surface);
            camera.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = 
                        camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                    captureBuilder.addTarget(surface);
                    session.setRepeatingRequest(captureBuilder.build(), null, null);
            }
        ..
}
```

in 'onSurfaceTextureAvailable()', cameraMangaer open camera with id and create each capture session and request

then setRequest.